# Execution failed for task ':shuftipro:publishReleasePublicationToSonatypeRepository'

Tags: android, maven

Execution failed for task ':shuftipro:publishReleasePublicationToSonatypeRepository'.

> Failed to publish publication 'release' to repository 'sonatype'
> Could not GET 'https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/io/github/PFZeeshan/dumy_instabug/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I faced this issue while publishing the library on maven central

I want to publish library on maven central repository

Comment: Obviously you don't have access... Do you have access credentials etc.